# Could not find a generator for route error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass arguments from a the slider page to the `MovieInfo` page:

```
I/flutter ( 6196): Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/MovieInfo", Instance of 'Arguments') in the _WidgetsAppState.
I/flutter ( 6196): Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate
I/flutter ( 6196): this route.
I/flutter ( 6196): Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
I/flutter ( 6196):  1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
I/flutter ( 6196):  2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
```

My main file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movie/arguments.dart';
import 'package:movie/pages/MovieInfo.dart';
import 'package:movie/pages/Serieses.dart';
import 'package:movie/pages/episodes.dart';
import 'package:movie/pages/livetv.dart';
import 'package:movie/pages/types.dart';
import 'pages/Home.dart';
import 'pages/ChooseLocation.dart';
import 'pages/loading.dart';
import 'pages/Movies.dart';
import 'pages/playvideo.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/Movies',
    onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
      if (settings.name == '/videoPlay') {
        final args = settings.arguments as Arguments;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              VideoPlayerApp(url: args.url, dataSource: args.dataSource),
        );
      } else if (settings.name == '/episodes') {
        final args = settings.arguments as Arguments;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              episodes(SeriesName: args.name, SeriesPath: args.path),
        );
      } else if (settings.name == '/MovieInfo') {
        final args = settings.arguments as Arguments;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => MovieInfo(name: args.name, path: args.path));
      }
      return null;
    },
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => Loading(),
      '/location': (context) => ChoosLocation(),
      '/home': (context) => Home(),
      '/Movies': (context) => Movies(),
      '/Series': (context) => Series(),
      '/liveTv': (context) => liveTv(),
      '/Types': (context) => Types()
    },
  ));
}
```

My `MovieInfo` screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

class MovieInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  late String name;
  late String path;
  MovieInfo({required this.name, required this.path});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 300,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6.0, sigmaY: 6.0),
                  child: ImageFiltered(
                    imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6.0, sigmaY: 6.0),
                    child: Image(
                      image: NetworkImage(path),
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 760),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('watch'),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                      "In the application main() method, call SystemChrome. setPreferredOrientations() with the list of preferred orientations that your app supports. To lock the device to a single orientation, you can pass a list with a single item. For a list of all the possible values, check out DeviceOrientation ."),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is where I made a column of Carousel sliders:

```
child: Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 200,
      height: double.maxFinite,
      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      child: Column(children: [
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            _scrollToPosition(200);
          },
          title: Text(
            'Drama',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )
      ]),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollcontroller,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            CSlider(
              list: movies,
              name: 'Top movies',
            ),
            CSlider(
              list: movies,
              name: 'Horror',
            ),
            CSlider(
              list: movies,
              name: 'Drama',
            ),
            CSlider(
              list: movies,
              name: 'Kids',
            ),
            CSlider(
              list: movies,
              name: 'Shows',
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

I checked it a lot but no result! I couldn't figure where the exception is happening.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but this is the most modern way of handling in-app navigation: https://pub.dev/packages/go_router

Answer (score 0):

From the error message and the code you've provided, it seems the issue is with how you've set up your route generation in the `MaterialApp` widget.

**1. Route Generation Overlap:**
You're using both `onGenerateRoute` and `routes`. It's better to stick with one for clarity. I'd recommend using `onGenerateRoute` since you're passing arguments.

**2. Undefined Routes:**
Currently, if none of the conditions in `onGenerateRoute` match, you're returning `null`. Instead, consider returning a default route or an error page.

**3. Argument Type:**
Ensure that when you're navigating to `/MovieInfo`, you're passing the correct `Arguments` type.

Here's a revised `onGenerateRoute`:

```dart
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  if (settings.arguments is Arguments) {
    final args = settings.arguments as Arguments;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/videoPlay':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => VideoPlayerApp(url: args.url, dataSource: args.dataSource),
        );
      case '/episodes':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => episodes(SeriesName: args.name, SeriesPath: args.path),
        );
      case '/MovieInfo':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MovieInfo(name: args.name, path: args.path),
        );
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ErrorPage()); // Consider adding an ErrorPage for unmatched routes
    }
  } else {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ErrorPage()); // Handle cases where arguments aren't of type 'Arguments'
  }
},
```

**4. Navigation Tip:**
When navigating, ensure you're using:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/MovieInfo', arguments: Arguments(name: 'MovieName', path: 'MoviePath'));
```

Lastly, double-check other parts of your code that involve navigation to ensure they're set up correctly.

Comment: I am obligated to use both "routes" and "onGenerateRoute" because i have some pages that need arguments and some the don't

Comment: Okay, I have added a modified solution to my previous answer in order for you to use both route and onGenerateRoute

Answer (score 0):

If you're obliged to use both `routes` and `onGenerateRoute`, that's perfectly fine. The key is to ensure they work harmoniously.

**1. Handling Routes with No Arguments:**
For routes that don't require arguments, continue using the `routes` property as you've done.

**2. Handling Routes with Arguments:**
For routes that require arguments, use the `onGenerateRoute` property. Ensure that you handle the route generation properly, especially for the `/MovieInfo` route.

**3. Undefined Routes:**
When none of the conditions in `onGenerateRoute` match, you're returning `null`. This can lead to the error you're seeing. Instead, consider handling this scenario by either redirecting to a default route or displaying an error page.

Here's a slightly adjusted `onGenerateRoute`:

```dart
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  if (settings.arguments is Arguments) {
    final args = settings.arguments as Arguments;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/videoPlay':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => VideoPlayerApp(url: args.url, dataSource: args.dataSource),
        );
      case '/episodes':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => episodes(SeriesName: args.name, SeriesPath: args.path),
        );
      case '/MovieInfo':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MovieInfo(name: args.name, path: args.path),
        );
      default:
        break; // Let the 'routes' property handle it
    }
  }
  return null; // This will allow the 'routes' property to take over for routes without arguments
},
```

**4. Navigation:**
When navigating to routes that require arguments, use:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/MovieInfo', arguments: Arguments(name: 'MovieName', path: 'MoviePath'));
```

By structuring it this way, you allow both `routes` and `onGenerateRoute` to coexist, with `onGenerateRoute` handling routes that require arguments and `routes` handling the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

What was causing the error is the `OrientationBuilder`, so I resolved it by removing the `OrientationBuilder`.